# Fatal error: Class xxx contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php

I learn PHP and I have problem:

```
<?php
class ProtectVis
{
    abstract protected function countMoney();
    protected $wage;

    protected function setHourly($hourly)
    {
        $money = $hourly;
        return $money;
    }
}

class ConcreteProtect extends ProtectVis
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->countMoney();
    }
    protected function countMoney()
    {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
$worker = new ConcreteProtect();
```

Now I have error:

> Fatal error: Class ProtectVis contains 1 abstract method and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (ProtectVis::countMoney) in

Why?

Comment: You should define a function with name `countMoney` in class `ConcreteProtect`

Comment: This function is defined.

Comment: You must declare class `ProtectVis` as `abstract` as it contains an `abstract` method.

Comment: *"Why?"* -- because the PHP definition of [abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) says so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the OOP principles, every class, that contains at least one abstract method is considered abstract as well.From the PHP Manual:

> Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract.

So you should change

```
class ProtectVis
```

with

```
abstract class ProtectVis
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare abstract class for ProtectVis because you are using abstract method

```
<?php
    abstract class ProtectVis
    {
        abstract protected function countMoney();
        protected $wage;

        protected function setHourly($hourly)
        {
            $money = $hourly;
            return $money;
        }
    }

    class ConcreteProtect extends ProtectVis
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->countMoney();
        }
        protected function countMoney()
        {
            echo "ok";
        }
    }
```